# SQLUnappropiate Data Population

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, sql

**PHP code**

```
 $qBasicRslt = mysqli_query($conn , $qBasic) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$json_array[] = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qBasicRslt))
{
 $json_array[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($json_array);
```

**SQL query_**

```
SELECT  `user`.`passwrd` AS Pass, `user`.`status` AS status,
        `useraccounts`.`Balance` AS bal, `useraccounts`.`AccountID` AS AccID,
        `accounts`.`AccountNo` AS Accno
FROM `user`
LEFT JOIN `useraccounts` ON `user`.`email` = `useraccounts`.`email`
LEFT JOIN `accounts` ON `accounts`.`AccountID` = `useraccounts`.`AccountID`
WHERE user.email = 'abc@testmail.com'
```

**this is how my data is coming**

[image]

data on console.log is this

```
[[],{"0":"12345","Pass":"12345","1":"active","status":"active","2":"0.260000000","bal":"0.260000000","3":"3","AccID":"3","4":"1LKHakRqzYi6K7sSDHmV3FirMUpN9YNMYQ","Accno":"1LKHakRqzYi6K7sSDHmV3FirMUpN9YNMYQ"}]
```

**jquery code**

```
 success: function(data) {
           for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
             var row = $('<tr><td>' + data[i].Pass+ '</td><td>' + data[i].status + '</td><td>' + data[i].bal +'</td><td>' + data[i].Accno +'</td><td>' + data[i].AccID  + '</td></tr>');            
            $('#wallet').append(row);
        }
```

instead of displaying json_encoded data this function is displaying undefined in the table.and var row contains `[object][object]`

Comment: im wandering from 3 days. plz help me out i will be thankful to you

Comment: Add `console.log(data)` to your function; what's the output? Also, can you show the rest of your ajax function, and the relevant PHP?

Comment: You should include also the php server side script that is returning the response

Comment: yes sir i have edited this.plz have look. and points out my mistake.

Comment: Add this line before the for loop 
var data = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: it worked but before displaying the data the first row in a table  displays this "undefined undefined undefined undefined"

Comment: Please have a look to my answer below ..

Comment: Do you have `header("Content-Type: application/json");` in your PHP? And use `$.getJSON()` for this instead of `$.ajax()` (that way you don't have to `JSON.parse()` yourself). Also, the console output shows that the first element of the response array is an empty array, that's why the first row is full of `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
success: function(data) {
    var data = JSON.parse(data);
    for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        var row = $('<tr><td>' + data[i].Pass+ '</td><td>' + data[i].status + '</td><td>' + data[i].bal +'</td><td>' + data[i].Accno +'</td><td>' + data[i].AccID  + '</td></tr>');            
        $('#wallet').append(row);
    }
```

And the PHP:

```
$qBasicRslt = mysqli_query($conn , $qBasic) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
$json_array = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($qBasicRslt))
{
 $json_array[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($json_array);
```